# Overlay a figure on top of Openstreet map using Bokeh?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, bokeh

How do I overlay a figure over a map(not google maps but OpenStreet maps) using Bokeh?

Figure 1: Austin city watershed to be plotted over map

[image]

currently my code generates figure 1 which is poor and needs to be overlaid over a map to make better sense.

Pandas DataFrame which is converted into figure shown in figure 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Convert the shapefile coordinates of lat and long to web mercator coordinates and use any available WMTS tile source to overlay the data on the map. Also provide the x and y range of the city you are interested in mercator coordinates.